# Walk through directory structure and move files with certain extensions up one level

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I try recursively walk through folders and move one level up some files. Such as PDF & DOC.
Structure of folders is:
Folder 1 -> folder 2-> folder 3 -> folder(doc)->  *.doc, folder(mp3)-> *.mp3.

I need to change it like this:
Folder 1 -> folder 2-> folder 3 -> folder(doc), *.doc, folder(mp3), *.mp3.

So I have a lot of such folders. And do this manually isn't possible.

I tried make script:
v1.0

```
For /R %%G in (*.doc,*.mp3) do move %%G ../
```

v1.1

```
For /R %%G in (*.doc,*.mp3) do move %%~nxG ../
```

v1.2

```
For /R %%G in (*.doc,*.mp3) do (
set B=%%~nxG
move %%B  ../
```

But it doesn't work.
What I'm doing wrong?

If I do this manually:

CD folder 1
CD folder 2
CD folder 3
CD folder(doc)
MOVE *.doc ../

It's works!

I will be grateful for any advice!

Comment: remove the trailing `/`. Also quote the `%%G` var in the move command so it  can handle spaces in directory and file names `for /R %%G in (*.doc,*.mp3) do move "%%G" ..`

Comment: `For /R %%G in (*.doc,*.mp3) do move "%%G" "%%~PG.."` Note that your `..` reference specify _the parent of the **current** directory_, not the parent of each file! `for /R` command does _not_ change the current directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly what is needed!!!

Comment: @Aacini sorry my fall. I'm first time on stackoverflow. Please post your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For /R %%G in (*.doc,*.mp3) do move "%%G" "%%~PG.."
```

Note that your `..` reference specify *the parent of the **current** directory*, not the parent of each file! `for /R` command does *not* change the current directory.